# Find only podcasts from a single country / language

Tags: itunes, podcasts

Is there any way to make iTunes (or some command line tool, perhaps) show podcasts only from one particular country / in one particular language?

Or, to put it differently, to hide all *American* podcasts, because they are so many and often completely drown content from other countries.

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac in iTunes, on the store podcasts page, click on the country flag at the bottom right hand corner, and then select a store for the country you're interested in. You'll then be able to view podcasts for that country, view them in categories, and download them.

Comment: Wow! I actually never really noticed that, because you have to scroll to the very bottom. Now the content is more localised, but there are still many American podcasts showing up, in particular when searching for a word that's a loanword from English. Is there any way to effectively lock podcasts to a single language / country; alternatively hide all American podcasts? Is there maybe some Unix CLI tool that lets you do advanced searches like this?

Comment: iTunes search isn't that advanced. But switching to a particular country's store is going to help a lot. In a non English-speaking country the easy answer is to use relevant non-English words to avoid that problem. If I search for "Wissenschaft" in the German iTunes store, I get approx 100 matches with no English matches at all (unsurprisingly!). "Science" still gives predominately German podcasts results. On the UK store, many if not most results are still from the UK. "Science UK" gives even more.

Answer (score 1):

This Apple page lets you create a JSON/XML "hot list" of podcasts (and other content types) for a particular country: https://rss.itunes.apple.com/.

Comment: This doesn't filter podcasts by country of origin though. Just by popularity by users in that country.